# Hash navigation; Either animate transitions with CSS3 or disable CSS3 hashtag navigation and use jQuery. But how?

Tags: jquery, css, transition, hashtag

Both CSS3 and jQuery can implement hash link navigation. But I cannot get the transition to be animated with CSS3. And I can't turn the CSS3 hash link fallowing off on browsers that support it resulting in both jQuery and CSS3 wanting to do the movement and CSS3 winning 9 times out of ten.

In this first jsfiddle is somewhat what I want my page to look like, navigation is done automatically by the browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/mg7Bw/2/

This second jsfiddle contains the same page but with jQuery loaded along with a simple script that is supposed to do do some fancy animation when the links are pressed, but is too slow most of the times. But if you click enough times you will see the animation once or twice.

http://jsfiddle.net/XHSyV/

Doing the transitions in jQuery or CSS3 has their advantages and disadvantages. Mostly I would like to have both. If the browser can do CSS3 transitions, send way less code. If the browser can't, send jQuery-code. But most of all I just want one method that works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got one solution here which is based on jQuery: Switch out the hashchange lib with localsscroll library and modify the source accordingly. Look at the fallowing jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XHSyV/1/

The only thing that has to be added is an updater for the hashtag.

EDIT: Adding hash:true to the localScroll fixed this:

http://jsfiddle.net/XHSyV/2/

Answer (score 1):

Take a Look at [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) - it will add CSS classes to the `html` tag so you're aware of whether the user's browser supports CSS3 transitions or not.

Along these lines:

```
.csstransitions #someselector:hover {
    // do some fancy css3 transition here
}

$('.nocsstransitions #someselector').on('mouseover', function(){
    // do nifty jQuery animation
}
```